# How to draw a graph that can indicate the values when the mouse moves to some part of the graph in python and put it on the web page?

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, cgi

I'm writing a web interface for a database of genes values of some experiments with CGI in Python and I want to draw a graph for the data queried. I'm using matplotlib.pyplot, draw a graph, save it, and perform it on the web page. But usually there are many experiments queried hence there are a lot of values. Sometimes I want to know which experiment does one value belong to because it's a big value, whereas it's hard to identify because the picture is small in size. The names of the experiments are long strings so that it will mess the x axis if I put all the experiment names on the x axis.

So I wonder if there is a way to draw a graph that can interact with users, i.e. if I point my mouse to some part on the graph, there would be one small window appears and tells me the exact value and what is the experiment name here. And the most important is, I can use this function when I put the graph on the web page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is basically [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) rendering of your plots. As far as I know, there are currently three great ways of achieving this, all under rapid development:

- [MPLD3](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3) for creating graphs with Matplotlib and serving them as interactive web graphics (see [examples in Jake's blog post](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/19/a-d3-viewer-for-matplotlib/)).
- [Plotly](https://plot.ly/api/python) where you can either generate the plots directly via Plotly or from Matplotlib figures (e.g. using [matplotlylib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlylib)) and have them served by Plotly.
- [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/) if you do not mind moving away from Matplotlib.